# rule based information extraction from raw text

Tags: nlp, text-processing, named-entity-recognition

I have a some phrases from aviation communication domain for eg: " Metro tower, 4 Delta Tango Charlie, request climb to flight level 350, wind 220" In this case

```
"metro tower" = Air traffic control tower name,
"four Delta Tango Charlie" = airplane call sign ,
"requset climb to flight level 350" = type of clearance request,
"350" = flight level
"wind 220" = wind info
```

I need to separate and extract these values corresponding to the tag names mentioned above to be used in later processing. As per my research I have figured out that this could be achieved by using custom Named Entity Recognition classes and rules, but I am not clear if this is the most efficient way to do it since this is to be used in a chat application and the processing time and response time has to be really quick. Please tell me if there are any other algorithms or techniques to do this.

Next problem is "four Delta Tango Charlie" part which consist of numbers and phonetic alphabet (A=Alpha, B=Bravo, C=Charlie,P=papa etc). What are the possible ways of creating a term dictionary for this alphabet and use the dictionary to extract the call sign from the raw text ?

Please also tell me what sought of algorithms could be used to solve my problem

Comment: What are the parameters? How many entities do you want to look up (10s, 100s, 1000s, more?). How many messages do you want to process per second? Depending on these parameters, you should use a list of regexes or lucene, or something in between. 
Or are these entities open ended beyond regexes (obviously wind can be followed by many numbers, but how about the requests).

Comment: Parameters are same as the entities, Actually this is for a an assignment and that is why i am concerned about performance not because of real application, number of entities will be less than 10,  it wont be used by multiple users at once just be 1 person so will not be even 1 message per second, wind and similar ones can be capped at 3 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Classical Named Entity Recognition (NER) is usually statistical (CRF, neural networks) and is trained on a large annotated corpus. If you do not have such a corpus, you cannot go this route. (Moreover, these are mostly not *named* entities but simply entities).

Instead I would simply search for the items on the list. With the parameters you mentioned you can use brute force, but since you mentioned it is an assignment, you should probably use something smarter.

You might want to compile all the items to search for into a finite state automaton (see  [Aho Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm)). The states can be tokens or simply letters.

Standardization of the phonetic alphabet depends on ambiguity (is *Charlie* always *C*? or can it be literally *Charlie* in some contexts). It can be done as a preprocessing step,  postprocessing step or it can be compiled into the search algorithm (using a transducer instead of an automaton).

You might also want to use token [regexes in Stanford NLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html). Or Apache Lucene.